# Pandas multi level ranking

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Consider I have a dataframe like this

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

arr = np.random.random((2, 4))
mdf = pd.DataFrame({'cid': [0, 1]})
pdf = pd.DataFrame({'doc_id': ['d1', 'd1', 'd2', 'd2'], 'passage_id': [0, 1, 0, 1]})
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(mdf.join(pdf, how='cross'))
df = pd.DataFrame({'score': arr.flatten()}, index=index)
```

df:

```
                             score
cid     doc_id  passage_id  
c1      d1       p1          0.708722
                 p2          0.975350
        d2       p1          0.326029
                 p2          0.979832
c2      d1       p1          0.147153
                 p2          0.381807
        d2       p1          0.525054
                 p2          0.245478
```

First I want to compute the passage rank for each document, which I can do like this:

`df['prank'] = df.groupby(level=[0, 1]).score.rank(ascending=False, method='dense')`

It will give me

```
                             score       prank
cid     doc_id  passage_id  
c1      d1       p1          0.708722      2
                 p2          0.975350      1  
        d2       p1          0.326029      2
                 p2          0.979832      1  
c2      d1       p1          0.384715      1
                 p2          0.181807      2
        d2       p1          0.525054      1
                 p2          0.245478      2
```

Now I also want to compute the document rank for each cid. I define document rank as the rank of the top ranked passage like the following table.

How do I get this table ?

```
                             score       prank  drank
cid     doc_id  passage_id  
c1      d1       p1          0.708722      2      2
                 p2          0.975350      1      2
        d2       p1          0.326029      2      1
                 p2          0.979832      1      1
c2      d1       p1          0.384715      1      2
                 p2          0.181807      2      2
        d2       p1          0.525054      1      1 
                 p2          0.245478      2      1
```

In the above example document (c1, d1) has rank 2 because the rank 1 passage of (c1, d1) has lower score than the rank 1 passage of (c1, d2)

Similarly (c2, d1) has rank 2 and (c2, d2) is rank 1 (0.384715 < 0.525054)

**EDIT**

This is the solution I came up with

```py
# Compute the document ranks
dranks = df.loc[df.prank == 1].groupby(level=0).score.rank(ascending=False, method='dense').droplevel(2)

# Drop the 3rd level index, now you can assign the dranks
df = df.reset_index(2)
df['drank'] = dranks

# Add the index back
df.set_index('passage_id', append=True)
```

Is there a more cleaner solution using groupby maybe, I don't like the dropping and adding of indices

Answer (score 0):

This solution first ranks all passages in a cid group, then within each cid/doc_id group, assign all members to have the minimum rank. Then rank the doc_id groups. It feels like some of this is redundant somehow and there should be an easier way.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'cid': {0: 'c1', 1: 'c1', 2: 'c1', 3: 'c1', 4: 'c2', 5: 'c2', 6: 'c2', 7: 'c2'}, 
    'doc_id': {0: 'd1', 1: 'd1', 2: 'd2', 3: 'd2', 4: 'd1', 5: 'd1', 6: 'd2', 7: 'd2'}, 
    'passage_id': {0: 'p1', 1: 'p2', 2: 'p1', 3: 'p2', 4: 'p1', 5: 'p2', 6: 'p1', 7: 'p2'}, 
    'score': {0: 0.7087220000000001, 1: 0.97535, 2: 0.326029, 3: 0.9798319999999999, 4: 0.147153, 5: 0.381807, 6: 0.525054, 7: 0.24547800000000003}}
)

df = df.set_index(['cid','doc_id'])

df['prank'] = df.groupby(level=[0, 1]).score.rank(ascending=False, method='dense')

by_cid_rank = df.groupby(level=0).score.rank(ascending=False,method='dense') #rank passages for each cid group
min_rank_by_cid = by_cid_rank.groupby(level=[0,1]).transform('min') #assign the min score to each cid/doc_id group
df['drank'] = min_rank_by_cid.groupby(level=0).rank(ascending=True,method='dense') #rank the ranks

df
```